# Can't parse any data from a webpage

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

Running my script I get neither any results, nor any errors. I was trying to parse names from that page or anything which is easy to go with. Can't find out what's wrong with my script or how should i process it. Gonna paste below the elements within which documents are stored. Here is what I have tried with:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url="http://minitransat.geovoile.com/2015/"
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36'}

def scrape_info(main_link):
    response = requests.get(main_link,headers=headers).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)
    for item in tree.xpath("//div[starts-with(@id,'line')]/text()"):
        print(item)

scrape_info(url)
```

Here are the elements:

```
<div id="line630" class="ARV" alt="1" rel="ffffff|4809850,-431719;3510,-301;-3430,810;2110,-3930;-140,-4500;-1320,-5390;-580,-5160;-810,-6650;-490,-6490;-1710,-7440;-3360,-5570;-3760,-5490;-2860,-5830;-2660,-6510;-2400,-5860;-2030,-5440;-1630,-5360;-990,-5850;-690,-5870;420,-5390;10,-300;330,-5040;570,-6740;300,-2250;640,-2450;-1990,-770;350,-2390;480,-2690;50,-150;760,-3020;1140,-2800;600,-2250;1580,-2620;1150,-1740;1650,-1820;1560,-2030;840,-370;270,120;-510,330;-700,-650;-20,-70;-480,-1840;100,-2580;-40,-4930;-330,-5910;-2190,-6340;-2750,-5670;-2760,-5380;-200,-330;-3250,-5610;-3630,-5670;-3950,-4620;-3340,-3220;-3880,-4950;-3150,-6790;-3290,-6370;-2850,-6790;-2530,-6290;-160,-400;-2550,-6390;-2110,-6460;-2530,-5710;-20,-1800;-170,-840;280,-1580;-590,-7500;-410,-6090;-330,-5530;-560,-5960;-1320,-6590;-1300,-6760;400,-7500;-480,-6800;-1370,-6760;-490,-7290;240,-7260;-3790,-1100;-4660,-960;-4770,-1540;-4780,-1570;-4580,-1330;-300,-60;-4890,-1360;-4960,-1350;-5510,-900;-5400,1000;-5710,400;-5530,1410;-340,90;-5750,630;-5810,650;-5700,930;-5850,550;-5760,-660;-11050,-9610;-6720,-6510;-8380,-6700;-10540,-6540;-9070,-7260;-8340,-5930;-7900,-3970;-6980,-5810;-390,-280;-6960,-5550;-7050,-5140;-8010,-2090;-8250,-4060;-8350,-4790;-8100,-4180;-7140,-3100;-7430,-4430;-7040,-4280;-6730,-4120;-6140,-4270;-6060,-3570;-6650,-4000;-6950,-4290;-6800,-4890;-6430,-3890;-6040,-3520;-6640,-3890;-6530,-3430;-6890,-3770;-6090,-3560;-6540,-4030;-7020,-4180;-6090,-3840;-6650,-4520;-6790,-3920;-6430,-3660;-5070,-2570;-6510,-4180;-7120,-4350;-6120,-3700;-4900,-3030;-4880,-2890;-6070,-4260;-7780,-5480;-7590,-4860;-7840,-5370;-6430,-4510;-6130,-2320;-5480,-1250;-5250,-1250;-5930,-1150;-6480,-1610;-6050,-1560;-5940,-2040;-6730,-2360;-7750,-2020;-8300,-2430;-8060,-2960;-7910,-3070;-7940,-4790;-8710,-6050;-8750,-5100;-8350,-4410;-8290,-5410;-7140,-4120;-7410,-4040;-6680,-5590;-6250,-4030;-6580,-4820;-6420,-4710;-7800,-4520;-7340,-6340;-6870,-6380;-6730,-5530;-6710,-4640;-6080,-5410;-5380,-5760;-5590,-2020;-6360,-6070;-6280,-4920;-7070,-4770;-6310,-4870;-7100,-5360;-6280,-6170;-7100,150;-7950,1370;-9290,1280;-9160,1890;-8770,1770;-10060,3430;-9440,3090;-9600,3560;-9190,4120;-9280,3830;-8300,2170;-7860,2390;-7820,1780;-6760,2060;-7990,3810;-9100,4440;-8620,2500;-8940,4410;-8360,4660;-7990,4040;-8170,4920;-9310,6130;-9000,4360;-9000,5700;-8200,-3440;-9050,-6640;-9040,-6000;-9340,-7090;-7630,-4570;-15560,-7980;-7520,-5420;-7780,-6030;-8810,-5180;-7640,-5140;-6900,-6140;-6950,-6470;-7490,-5020;-7200,-4090;-6340,-6930;-320,-340;-6850,-6740;-5830,-5870;-4690,-950;-5680,3580;-5110,5170;-5650,5480;-6320,5250;-6310,6130;-5410,6020;-6030,-810;-6100,-3690;-6010,-3830;-6120,-4400;-6370,-4140;-6680,-4400;-5340,-5120;-5030,-5220;-5240,-5430;-4790,-590;-5230,4380;-4770,2020;-5090,2970;-5400,3690;-5010,4530;-5360,4470;-5920,4460;-5030,4080;-5020,5390;-5420,5140;-6570,5180;-6290,1540;-7120,-3840;-7060,-3340;-6240,-3170;-230,-140;-6750,-3470;-6470,-3150;-6200,-3030;-5420,-1880;-5190,-2990;-4920,-2940;-5270,-4450;-5420,-2490;-5050,-1510;-4900,-1720;-4910,-1820;-5400,-1350;-4920,-1470;-4970,-1430;-5520,-2650;-5140,-4030;-5450,-3200;-5150,-4510;-5550,-4280;-5370,-3610;-5520,-3580;-5570,-1860;-6040,-3100;-5440,-3950;-5970,-4380;-6660,-3750;-5650,-4060;-6080,-4030;-6400,-4180;-5540,-4390;-4650,-3900;-4460,-3890;-4770,-4990;-4290,-4290;-3950,-5050;-4060,-1530;-5440,1560;-5790,1970;-5460,1770;-5140,1540;-5260,1990;-5090,2120;-4660,2470;-5290,2750;-5260,2840;-5870,3820;-5490,3530;-5820,4760;-5650,4780;-6310,4240;-6520,3620;-7150,3760;-7530,3760;-6890,2420;-6970,2590;-6940,2710;-7160,2470;-6600,1160;-6240,-1300;-6390,-1170;-6980,-1550;-7720,-2050;-7980,-2640;-8560,-1830;-8520,-2310;-7600,-2390;-6840,-2540;-6890,-1850;-6550,-1430;-5690,-580;-4960,-630;-5210,630;-4770,1320;-4860,1610;-5050,1440;-5490,1660;-5760,1590;-6040,2070;-5890,2250;-5280,1430;-5440,880;-4790,680;-3250,0;-1590,-4980;-1110,-5390;-1930,-6600;-1480,-6630;-1960,-6960;-2480,-6940;-2750,-6180;-3740,-7150;-3750,-6120;-3940,-6330;-4060,-6790;-4780,-7240;-5480,-6580;-5360,-6950;-5170,-7700;-4990,-7090;-2440,-3795;-2440,-3795;-4600,-7440;-4800,-7010;-4590,-6900;-5120,-6550;-7080,-390;-7740,760;-8000,40;-7990,-110;-9250,-100;-9330,-90;-6260,-2960;-2230,-3880;-1800,-3720;-2170,-4570;-1970,-4370;-2950,-1740;-3940,-750;-4090,-490;-2840,-2390;-2370,-3920;-1990,-3090;-3490,-270;-3580,70;-2730,-1770;-1790,-3740;-1920,-4270;-2020,-4560;-1530,-3640;670,-650;-50,-90;-410,-250;0,0;-10,0;0,-10;0,10;10,-10;-10,0;0,0;10,0;0,0;-10,10;10,0;0,0;-10,-10;0,10;10,0;0,0;-10,0;10,0;-10,0;0,-10;0,0;10,0;0,10;0,0;0,-10;0,0;0,10;0,0;0,-10;0,10;-10,-20,1680|">
  <q>9</q>
  <p>Nicolas D'estais</p>
  <p>Librairie Cheminant</p>
  <p>Arrivé le 27/09/2015 à 04:44:44 UTC</p>
  <p>En 7j 15h 14min 44s</p>
  <dfn class="hulls1">
    <dt>2015/09/27T14:27:00Z</dt>
    <dl>28.96470;-13.53840</dl>
    <dd>243</dd>
  </dfn>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The script is correct but the data you are receiving from the given url does not contain any div tag having id starting with line. Second thing is that you are retrieve something which is not there.
Below is the output from your url:

```
   <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Mini Transat 2015</title>
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <meta name="viewport" content="     initial-scale=1.0,width=device-width,user-scalable=0,minimum-scale=1.0,     maximum-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/2015/_elements/default/css/     reset.css?v=63583546506" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/2015/home/main.css?v=63580587082" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/2015/_elements/custom/      home.css?v=63578166019" />
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/2015/_elements/plugins/      jquery/jquery.1.12.2.js?v=63595118555"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/2015/home/     main.js?v=63577584956"></script>

      <script>
        $(window).load(function () {
          GeovoileHomePage.chrono.start("{0}<i>j</i> {1}<i>h</i> {2}<i>min</i> {3}<i>     s</i>", "2015/10/31 14:10:00 GMT+0", "2015/10/31 14:10:00 GMT+0");
        });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <header>
        <a id="logo" href="http://www.minitransat-ilesdeguadeloupe.fr/" target="_blank      "></a>
        <div id="chrono"></div>
        <div id="menu"><tt><span></span></tt><nav>
  <ul id="legs"><li><a href="?leg=1" rel="1"><big>Étape 1</big><small>E 1</small></a>     </li><li class="on"><a href="?leg=2" rel="2"><big>Étape 2</big><small>E 2</small></a    ></li></ul>
  <ul class="pages" rel="1"><li rel="tracker_1"><a href="tracker/?leg=1">Cartographie     </a></li><li rel="mainboard_1"><a href="widgets/mainboard/?leg=1">Classements</a></     li><li rel="graphics_1"><a href="widgets/graphics/?leg=1">Graphiques</a></li><li rel    ="statistics_1"><a href="widgets/statistics/?leg=1">Statistiques</a></li><li rel="     general_1"><a href="widgets/general/?leg=1">Général</a></li></ul>
  <ul class="pages on" rel="2"><li rel="tracker_2"><a href="tracker/?leg=2">      Cartographie</a></li><li rel="mainboard_2"><a href="widgets/mainboard/?leg=2">      Classements</a></li><li rel="graphics_2"><a href="widgets/graphics/?leg=2">     Graphiques</a></li><li rel="statistics_2"><a href="widgets/statistics/?leg=2">    Statistiques</a></li><li rel="general_2"><a href="widgets/general/?leg=2">Général</a    ></li></ul></nav></div>
      </header>
      <main><iframe id="tracker_1" src="_blank.html"></iframe><iframe id="mainboard_1"       src="_blank.html"></iframe><iframe id="graphics_1" src="_blank.html"></iframe><      iframe id="statistics_1" src="_blank.html"></iframe><iframe id="general_1" src="      _blank.html"></iframe><iframe id="tracker_2" src="_blank.html"></iframe><iframe       id="mainboard_2" src="_blank.html"></iframe><iframe id="graphics_2" src="     _blank.html"></iframe><iframe id="statistics_2" src="_blank.html"></iframe><    iframe id="general_2" src="_blank.html"></iframe></main>
      <footer>Mises à jour :  01h30  UTC • 03h00  UTC • 05h00  UTC • 08h00  UTC •       11h00  UTC • 14h00  UTC • 17h00  UTC • 19h00  UTC • 19h30  UTC • 20h00  UTC •       23h00  UTC<div id="time">{3}h{4} UTC|0</div></footer>
      <div id="finistere"></div><div id="bretagne"></div><a id="materne" href="http://      www.materne.fr/" target="_blank" title="www.materne.fr"></a><div id="minitransat      ">Douarnenez ► Lanzarote ► Pointe-à-Pitre</div>
    </body>
    <!--TRL_OK-->
  </html>
```

I tried to edit your script to see if the code actually works. Below is the modified code which gives me some output:
        import requests
        from lxml import html

```
    url="http://minitransat.geovoile.com/2015/"
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36'}

    def scrape_info(main_link):
        response = requests.get(main_link,headers=headers).text
        tree = html.fromstring(response)
        print(tree.xpath("//div/text()"))
```

this only contains one item so iterating on it is unnecessary.
Below is the output of this program:

```
['{3}h{4} UTC|0', 'Douarnenez ► Lanzarote ► Pointe-à-Pitre']
```

I hope this helps you. I suggest check the data that you are receiving in these kind of scenarios.

Comment: In short - if the page generates content by manipulating the DOM via AJAX requests/other javascript-y stuff, then it won't be present when using `requests`.